# Is python`s SysLogHandler nonBlocking?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python script that well periodically connect to haproxy socket, send a "show info" command and exit. This script will be used along with keepalived in order to determine, through this script, when to switch master/slave servers. Therefore, my goal is that my python script been non-blocking.

Within my script, i have initiated a SysLogHandler to send to my local syslogd various messages (exceptions e.t.c). However, i don't know if SysLogHandler is Blocking or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) on logging is the main point where you should start.

`SysLogHandler` is a subclass of `Handler`(There are many more. See the docs).

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.handle) is the relevant part that you are looking for I think.

I went a bit further and checked the actual implementation of Handler.
You can see that [it uses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b9fc317468d6a57eba41a88eb07b231232c2441c/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L796) [threading.RLock()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.RLock).

Comment: I am quite new to python programming so i didnt understand much. Could you further explain please?

Comment: Thanks for the references! That helped alot